# When I enter something into the form, it returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function outputItem() {
  var x = document.getElementById("form1");
  var item = x.elements["item"].value ;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = item ;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="output"></p>
</div>
<form id="form1">
  item: <input name="item" type="text" size="20">
</form>
<button onclick="outputItem()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

`elements` is a NodeList containing all the form controls in the form.

Normally, it will have a property named `foo` to go with a form control with `name="foo"`.

However, you are using the name `item` which has a [predefined value on NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item) so when you access it you get that function and not the form control.

This would have been more obvious had you debugged the code with `console.log(x.elements["item"])`.

---

Avoid using the `elements` NodeList. Use something else, such as `querySelector` instead.

```
function outputItem() {
  var item = document.querySelector('#form1[name="item"]'].value ;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = item ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
 var item = x.elements.namedItem("item").value ;
```

```js
function outputItem() {
  var x = document.getElementById("form1");
  var item = x.elements.namedItem("item").value ;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = item ;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="output"></p>
</div>
<form id="form1" >
  item: <input name="item" type="text" size="20">
</form>
<button onclick="outputItem()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're accessing the wrong element's value. You should directly get the input element you are inserting value in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id="output"></p>
    </div>
    <form id="form1">
        item: <input id="input1" name="item" type="text" size="20">
    </form>
    <button onclick="outputItem()">Add</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function outputItem() {
        var x = document.getElementById("input1");
        var item = x.value;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = item ;
    }
</script>
</html>
```